# Scanning Langston Hughes' "The South"

Tags: poetry, meter, langston-hughes

Here's the [poem](https://poets.org/poem/south-1) "The South" by Langston Hughes scanned by me (a non-native English speaker):

> The **la**zy, **laugh**ing **South**
> With **blood** **on** its **mouth**.
> The **sun**ny-**faced** **South**,
> **Beast**-**strong**,
> **Id**iot-**brained**.
> The **child**-**mind**ed **South**
> **Scratch**ing **in** the **dead** **fire’s** **ash**es
> **For** a **Ne**gro’s **bones**.
> **Cot**ton **and** the **moon**,
> **Warmth**, **earth**, **warmth**,
> The **sky**, the **sun**, the **stars**,
> The **magno**lia-**scent**ed **South**.
> **Beau**ti**ful**, **like** a **wo**man,
> Se**duc**tive **as** a **dark**-**eyed** **whore**,
> **Pa**ssionate, **cru**el,
> **Hon**ey-**lipped**, **sy**phi**lit**ic—
> That **is** the **South**.
> And **I**, who am **black**, would **love** her
> But she **spits** in my **face**.
> And **I**, who am **black**,
> Would **give** her **man**y **rare** **gifts**
> But she **turns** her **back** up**on** me.
> So **now** I **seek** the **North**—
> The **cold**-**faced** **North**,
> For **she**, they **say**,
> Is a **kind**er **mis**tress,
> And in her **house** my **child**ren
> **May** e**scape** the **spell** of the **South**.

Is my scansion accurate? If not, I would love corrections with explanations.

Comment: Scansions are subjective. If you give three people the same poem, you may get three different scansions. Your scansion is perfectly fine, but others would be, too—you could easily put two stress in the line "with **blood** on its **mouth.** or three stresses in the line "And **in** her **house** my **child**ren.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, @PeterShor!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here goes. My reading is different from yours in a few places:

```
|  x   ´ | x     ´   |  x   ´    |      
| The la | zy, laugh | ing South |

|   x    ´    |  x  x   ´     |
|  With blood | on its mouth. |

|  x   ´  |  x  ´  |  x   ´    |
| The sun | ny-fac | ed South, |

|    ´    ´     |
| Beast-strong, |

| ´ x |  x    ´     |
| Idi | ot-brained. |

| x   ´      |  ´  x  | ´     |
| The child- | minded | South |

|    ´   x   |  x  x  |   ´     ´   |  ´ x  |
| Scratching | in the | dead fire’s | ashes |

| x  x |  ´   x  |   ´    |
| For a | Negro’s | bones. |

|  ´  x  |  x   x    ´   |
| Cotton | and the moon, |

|    ´    |    ´   |    ´    |
| Warmth, | earth, | warmth, |

|  x   ´  |  x   ´   |  x    ´    |
| The sky,| the sun, | the stars, |

|  x   x  ´ |  x    ´  |   x    ´   |
| The magno | lia-scen | ted South. |

|   ´  x  x  |   x  x |  x  ´  |
| Beautiful, | like a | woman, |

|  x ´  |   x  x  | x   ´  |    ´     ´   |
| Seduc | tive as | a dark | -eyed whore, |

|  ´  x   x   |  ´ x   |
| Passionate, | cruel, |

|  ´  x   x     |  `  x     ´ x   |
| Honey-lipped, | sy phi | litic— |

|   ´   x |  x    ´    |
| That is | the South. |

|  x  ´  |  x   x   ´    |  x      ´   `  |
| And I, | who am black, | would love her |

|  x   x    ´   |  x  x   ´   |
| But she spits | in my face. |

|  x  ´  |  x   x   ´    | 
| And I, | who am black, |

|   x     ´  |  x   ´ |  x   ´  |   ´   |
| Would give | her ma | ny rare | gifts |

|  x   x  |   ´    x  |   ´  x |  ´   x  | 
| But she | turns her | back u | pon me. |

|  x  ´  | x   ´  |  x    ´    |
| So now | I seek | the North— |

|  x   ´    |  ´ x  |   ´    |
| The cold- | faced | North, |

|  x   ´   |   x   ´   |
| For she, | they say, |

|  ` x |  ´  x  |   ´   x   |
| Is a | kinder | mistress, |

|  x   x |  ´    ´   |  x   ´   x  |
| And in | her house | my children |

|  ´   x |   ´   x  |   ´    x |  x    ´    | 
| May es | cape the | spell of | the South. |
```

Here are the points of departure:

- *With blood **on** its mouth*. Prepositions are rarely stressed in English.
- ***Fa**ced* I read as two syllables, not one. Both times the word occurs, the line seems smoother that way.
- *Scratching **in** the dead fire’s ashes*. It would be really odd to stress the preposition here, I think.
- While ***For** a Negro's bones* gives you a nice catalectic trochaic line, I don't think a stress is syntactically or semantically warranted on *for*.
- *Cotton **and** the moon.* Conjunctions are not usually stressed unless semantically significant, and here I think it's just a conjunction, not meriting an augmentative emphasis. I.e., it's just joining together a list, not expressing wonder or surprise, as would be the case in *¿¡ You ate all the cake **and** all the ice-cream ?!*
- *The **magno**lia-scented South*. Why the stress on *mag*? That's not how the word is pronounced.
- *Beautiful, **like** a woman*. That seems unlikely to me.
- *Seductive **as** a dark-eyed whore*. I can see the argument that the line reads better with a half-stress on the *as*, but I think a pyrrhic balances out the spondee at the end.
- *Honey-**lipped**, syphilitic*. I think a stress on *lipped* both runs counter to how I'd expect to hear the compound word being pronounced, and throws the line off-kilter rhythmically.
- *That **is** the South*. H'm, you could argue for a stress on *is*, but I think one on *that* makes better sense.

Note the preponderance of *I* statements in the list. That's how *I'd* scan the poem. I wouldn't go as far as @PeterShor and say that "scansions are subjective", but I do agree that scansion is an act of interpretation, and as such, not entirely objective. There is, however, a vast middle ground between subjective and objective; interpretations can be argued for and/or over, but some are clearly better than others.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, verbose! It’s also great to see you here after so long.

Comment: Great to be back! Thanks for your kind words.